# Cache won't update

Tags: browser-cache

How does cache affect HTML and CSS source code when browser is refreshed?

When I change my source code and refresh the browser, it does not take into account my updated  changes. I was told this is a result of cache stored in the browser.

Comment: Ctrl + F5 sometimes helps

Comment: Does this apply for both Mac and PC?